# Sailsjs socketio http status

Tags: express, socket.io, sails.js

I know I can call REST API of sails using socket.io. And return me the response. Following is a simple way to do that

```
socket.get("/", function (response) { console.log(response); })
```

But I also want the http status code along with response how I can get that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the API blueprints, then the response will return the status code in the event of an error.  For example, if there was a general server error, you'll get back:

```
{status: 500}
```

Otherwise, you'll get data in the response and you can assume the status was 200.

If you're using a custom controller action, then you can use any of the default responses (like `res.serverError()`, `res.forbidden()`, etc) to send back a status code, or you can set one yourself:

```
myAction: function (req, res) {

   return res.forbidden(); // Will send {status: 403}
   // OR
   return res.json({status:400, error: 'Bad request!'})

}
```

But if you just send the status using `res.json(500, {error: 'someError'})`, you won't be able to retrieve it on the client.

**Update**

On Sails v0.10.x, using the [new Sails socket client library](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails.io.js), the request methods (`io.socket.get`, `io.socket.post`, etc) have callbacks that accept *two* arguments: the first being the response body (equivalent to the response in the previous client library version), and the second being an expanded response object which includes the status code, headers and more.